# How to create a loop that appends new rows to CSV each time it loops?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, append

I'm working with an API in and trying to pull out a complete list of surveys by looping through every users API token. My idea for the loop is that it reads each API token (stored in a list) one at a time, stores the data, converts it to a pandas dataframe and then stores the data in a CSV file. I've so far created a script that successfully loops through the list of API tokens but just overwrites the CSV file each time. Here is my script currently:

```
apiToken = ["n0000000000001", "N0000000002"]

for x in apiToken:
    baseUrl = "https://group.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys"
    headers = {
        "x-api-token": x,
        }
    response = requests.get(baseUrl, headers=headers)
    surveys = response.text
    surveys2 = json.loads(response.text)
    surveys3 = surveys2["result"]["elements"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(surveys3)
    df.to_csv('survey_list.csv', index=False)
```

What changes do I need to make in order for the new rows to be appended on to the CSV rather than overwrite it?

Comment: You should create one general dataframe and for each loop ini apiToken, append the dataframe to the general dataframe. Then, outside of your loop, convert the general dataframe to CSV.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code? I'm struggling to work it out

Comment: @wild9 yes I can, is it still needed?

Comment: Yes please, I just can't get it right

Comment: @wild9 okay, I'll add a new answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is right, this should work. You make a list of the separate dataframes, and concat them together. This works if all the DataFrames in the list of DataFrames (dfs) have the same column names.

```
apiToken = ["n0000000000001", "N0000000002"]
dfs = []

for x in apiToken:
    baseUrl = "https://group.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys"
    headers = {
        "x-api-token": x,
        }
    response = requests.get(baseUrl, headers=headers)
    surveys = response.text
    surveys2 = json.loads(response.text)
    surveys3 = surveys2["result"]["elements"]
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(surveys3))

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
final_df .to_csv('survey_list.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the csv package you can append files to your csv as follows:

```
import csv
...
with open(filename,'a') as filecsv:
    writer = csv.writer(filecsv)
    line = # whatever csv line you want to append
    writer.writerow(line)
```